# WCF: How to cache collections from OData in client

Tags: c#, wcf, caching, client, odata

Is there a possibility to cache a collection, retrieved using WCF from an OData service.

The situation is the following:
I generated a WCF service client with Visual Studio 2015 using the metadata of the odata service. VS generated a class inheriting from `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext`. This class has some properties of type `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<T>`. The data of some of these properties change seldom. Because of performance reasons I want the WCF client to load these properties just the first time and not every time I use it in the code.

Is there a built in possibility to cache the data of these properties? Or can I tell the service client not to load specific proeprties newly every time.

Assuming the service client class is `ODataClient` and one of its properties is `Area, for now I get the values in the following way:

```cs
var client = new ODataClient("url_to_the_service");
client.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;

var propertyInfo = client.GetType().GetProperty("Area");
var area = propertyInfo.GetValue(client) as IEnumerable<object>;
```

The reason why I do this in such a complicated way is, that the client should be very generic: The properties to be handled can be configured in a configuration file.

*** EDIT ***

I already tried to find properties in the `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext` class or the `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<T>` class for the caching. But i wasn't able to find any.

Comment: Why not just implement that caching yourself? Wrap client access code in a separate class and implement caching should be not hard.

Comment: To avoid the extra afford, if there is a build in possibility that I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no "out of the box" caching concept on the client.  There are options for caching the output of a request on the server which is something you might want consider as well.  Googling "WCF Caching" would get you a bunch of info on this.

Regarding client side caching...@Evk is correct it is pretty straight forward.  Here is an sample using [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Caching;

namespace Services.Util
{
    public class CacheWrapper : ICacheWrapper
    {
        ObjectCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;

        public void ClearCache()
        {
            MemoryCache.Default.Dispose();
            _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        }

        public T GetFromCache<T>(string key, Func<T> missedCacheCall)
        {
            return GetFromCache<T>(key, missedCacheCall, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        }

        public T GetFromCache<T>(string key, Func<T> missedCacheCall, TimeSpan timeToLive)
        {
            var result = _cache.Get(key);
            if (result == null)
            {
                result = missedCacheCall();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    _cache.Set(key, result, new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(timeToLive) });
                }
            }

            return (T)result;
        }

        public void InvalidateCache(string key)
        {
            _cache.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is an example of code that uses the cache...**

```
private class DataAccessTestStub
        {
            public const string DateTimeTicksCacheKey = "GetDateTimeTicks";

            ICacheWrapper _cache;

            public DataAccessTestStub(ICacheWrapper cache)
            {
                _cache = cache;
            }

            public string GetDateTimeTicks()
            {
                return _cache.GetFromCache(DateTimeTicksCacheKey, () =>
                {
                    var result = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
                    Thread.Sleep(100); // Create some delay
                    return result;
                });
            }

            public string GetDateTimeTicks(TimeSpan timeToLive)
            {
                return _cache.GetFromCache(DateTimeTicksCacheKey, () =>
                {
                    var result = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
                    Thread.Sleep(500); // Create some delay
                    return result;
                }, timeToLive);
            }

            public void ClearDateTimeTicks()
            {
                _cache.InvalidateCache(DateTimeTicksCacheKey);
            }

            public void ClearCache()
            {
                _cache.ClearCache();
            }
        }
```

**And some tests if you fancy...**

```
 [TestClass]
public class CacheWrapperTest
{
    private DataAccessTestStub _dataAccessTestClass;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        _dataAccessTestClass = new DataAccessTestStub(new CacheWrapper());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetFromCache_ShouldExecuteCacheMissCall()
    {
        var original = _dataAccessTestClass.GetDateTimeTicks();
        Assert.IsNotNull(original);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetFromCache_ShouldReturnCachedVersion()
    {
        var copy1 = _dataAccessTestClass.GetDateTimeTicks();
        var copy2 = _dataAccessTestClass.GetDateTimeTicks();
        Assert.AreEqual(copy1, copy2);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetFromCache_ShouldRespectTimeToLive()
    {
        _dataAccessTestClass.ClearDateTimeTicks();
        var copy1 = _dataAccessTestClass.GetDateTimeTicks(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        var copy2 = _dataAccessTestClass.GetDateTimeTicks();
        Assert.AreEqual(copy1, copy2);

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        var copy3 = _dataAccessTestClass.GetDateTimeTicks();
        Assert.AreNotEqual(copy1, copy3);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void InvalidateCache_ShouldClearCachedVersion()
    {
        var original = _dataAccessTestClass.GetDateTimeTicks();

        _dataAccessTestClass.ClearDateTimeTicks();

        var updatedVersion = _dataAccessTestClass.GetDateTimeTicks();
        Assert.AreNotEqual(original, updatedVersion);
    }

}
```

Comment: I did not knew, that there is an cache implementation in the framework like `MemoryCache`. This helps a lot for implementing the cache I need. Thanks.